# Evaluating arithmetic expressions and plotting graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, math-expression-eval

I just got started with Python. I created some code, and I want to know what more experienced devs think about it. What can I do better? What to avoid?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Graphs - Calculate expression or draws a graph from given equation.

This is a conversion of my old program created at college at 2002y. 
Just to learn python at 2020y.

"""

import re
import operator
import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DEC_PLACES = 3      #number of decimal places after rounding

FUNCTIONS = {
    'sin': lambda x:math.sin(math.radians(x)),
    'cos': lambda x:math.cos(math.radians(x)),
    'tan': lambda x:math.tan(math.radians(x)),
    'ln': lambda x:math.log(x),
}

OPERS = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv,
    '^': operator.pow,    
}

OP_PRIO = {
    '(':0,
    '+':1,
    '-':1,
    ')':1,
    '*':2,
    '/':2,
    '^':3,
}

NUM_MATCH = re.compile(
'(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)'
'(?:[.][0-9]+)?'
)

FUN_MATCH = re.compile(
'(?:[a-z]{2,}[(])'
)

def checkBrackets(sFun):
    """
     Function checks brackets in string
     i: string with function
     r: 0 -> brackets failure / 1 -> brackets ok 
    """

    wynik = 0 # int result of scan

    if "(" or ")" in sFun:
        for x in sFun:
            if x == "(":
                wynik += 1
                continue
            elif x == ")":
                wynik -= 1
                continue

    if(wynik != 0): wynik = 0
    else: wynik = 1
    return wynik

def analizeOperations(sFun):
    """
     Function checks if there are two operators one after the other
     i: string with function
     r: true if ok / false when err
    """
    ok = True # returning var
    sFun.replace(" ","")
    for i in range(len(sFun)):
        if sFun[i] in OPERS:
            if i>=1:
                if sFun[i-1] in OPERS:
                    #two opers side by side
                    ok = False
                    break
    return ok    

def analizeOpAfterCB(sFun):
    """
     Function checks if there is operator after closing bracket
     i: string with function
     r: true if ok / false when err
    """
    ok = True # returning var
    sFun.replace(" ","")
    for i in range(len(sFun)):
        if sFun[i] == ")" and (i+1)<len(sFun):
            if sFun[i+1] != ")":
                if not sFun[i+1] in OPERS:
                    #missing operator after closing bracket
                    ok = False
                    break
    return ok    

def toRPN(sFun,x_val):
    """
    Function convert infix string to RPN
    i: string with function infix
    x_val: value for x variable
    r: RPN[] 
    """
    stos = []       #stack
    wyjscie = []    #exit string

    index = 0
    while index < len(sFun):
        expr = sFun[index:]
        is_num = NUM_MATCH.match(expr)
        is_fun = FUN_MATCH.match(expr)          
        if is_num:                              #if num put on wyjscie
            num = is_num.group(0)
            wyjscie.append(float(num))            
            index += len(num)
            continue            
        if is_fun:                              #if function put on stos
            fun = is_fun.group(0)
            fun = fun[:-1]                      #remove "("
            if fun in FUNCTIONS:
                stos.append(fun)
                index += len(fun)
                continue                
            else:
                raise("Błąd! Nieznana funkcja.")
        if sFun[index] == "(":                  #if "(" put on stos
            stos.append(sFun[index])
            index += 1
            continue
        if sFun[index] == ")":                  
            for i in range(len(stos)-1,0,-1):   #if ")" move all operands till "(" to wyjscie LIFO
                if stos[i] == "(":
                    del stos[i]
                    if stos[i-1] in FUNCTIONS:
                        wyjscie.append(stos[i-1])
                        del stos[i-1]
                    break
                else:
                    wyjscie.append(stos[i])
                    del stos[i]                
            index += 1
            continue
        if sFun[index].lower() == "x":                  #insert x value on wyjscie
            wyjscie.append(float(x_val))
            index += 1
            continue        
        if sFun[index] in OPERS:        
            if index == 0:                  #if this is first char of string insert 0.0 before it
                wyjscie.append(0.0)
            elif sFun[index-1] == "(":
                wyjscie.append(0.0)         #if operator is after openning bracket insert 0.0 before it
            if not stos:                        #if stos is empty insert operator
                stos.append(sFun[index])               
                index += 1
                continue
            if OP_PRIO[sFun[index]] > OP_PRIO[stos[-1]]:    #if oper in sFun has higher prio add it to stos
                stos.append(sFun[index])
                index += 1
                continue            
            else:                                               
                while len(stos):                                #if oper in sFun has prio <= oper in stos
                                                                #move all opers from stos to wyjscie with prio >= oper                     
                    if (OP_PRIO[stos[-1]]>OP_PRIO[sFun[index]]
                        or (
                            OP_PRIO[stos[-1]] == (OP_PRIO[sFun[index]] 
                            and OP_PRIO[sFun[index]]<3)
                        )
                    ): 
                        wyjscie.append(stos[-1])
                        del stos[-1]
                    else: break
                stos.append(sFun[index])
                index += 1                
    # move stos to wyjscie LIFO
    while len(stos):
        if stos[-1] not in ["(",")",]:
            wyjscie.append(stos[-1])
        del stos[-1]
    return wyjscie

def evalExpr(sFun, x_val = 1):
    """
    Function evaluate RPN string 
    i: string with function infix 
    x_val: value for x variable
    r: value
    """
    stos = [] #stack
    #check string
    if not checkBrackets(sFun):
        raise SyntaxError("The expression have unclosed brackets!")
    elif not analizeOperations(sFun):      
        raise SyntaxError("The expression have incorrectly written operators!")
    elif not analizeOpAfterCB(sFun):
        raise SyntaxError("Missing operator after closing bracket!")
    else:
        sRPN = toRPN(sFun,x_val)
        while len(sRPN):        
            if isinstance(sRPN[0],float):
                stos.append(sRPN[0])
                del sRPN[0]
                continue
            if sRPN[0] in OPERS:
                func = OPERS[sRPN[0]]           #get function for oper
                val = func(stos[-2],stos[-1])                
                del stos[-2:]                   #remove used vals from stos
                del sRPN[0]                     
                stos.append(val)
                continue
            if sRPN[0] in FUNCTIONS:
                func = FUNCTIONS[sRPN[0]]           #get function 
                val = func(stos[-1])                
                del stos[-1]                   #remove used vals from stos
                del sRPN[0]                     
                stos.append(val)
                continue    
        return round(stos[0],DEC_PLACES)        #return rounded result

def showHelp():
    print("Allowed operators and functions:")
    print("+-*/^")
    print("sin, cos, tan, ln")
    print("You can enter arithmetic expressions like:")
    print("2*(3-4)^2")
    print("2*sin(30-4*2)")
    print("or functions like:")
    print("2*x^2+3*x+1")
    print("2*sin(x)*x+1")

def main():    
    expr = input("Enter an arithmetic expression (type help for info):")    
    if expr.lower() == "help":
        showHelp()
        exit()
    if "x" in expr:
        option = input("Expression cotains 'x' variable, enter 'r' for range or 'v' for value:")
        while option.lower() != 'r' and option.lower() != 'v':
            option = input("Expression cotains 'x' variable, enter 'r' for range or 'v' for value:")
        if option == 'v':
            x_val = ''
            while not isinstance(x_val,float):
                try:
                    x_val = float(input("Enter x value:"))
                except:
                    print("That was no valid number.")
            print("{0} = {1}".format(expr,evalExpr(expr,x_val)))
        else:
            x_val = ''
            x_start = ''
            x_end = ''
            x_step = ''
            while (not isinstance(x_start,float) 
                    and not isinstance(x_end,float)
                    and not isinstance(x_step,float)
                ):
                try:
                    x_start, x_end, x_step = map(float,input("Enter start value, end value and step for range (eg.: 0,5,1): ").split(","))
                except:
                    print("That was no valid number.")
            #make a graph
            x = []
            y = []
            #calculating values
            i = x_start
            while i <= x_end:
                x.append(i)
                y.append(evalExpr(expr, i))
                i += x_step
            # plotting the points  
            plt.plot(x, y) 
            # naming the x axis 
            plt.xlabel('x') 
            # naming the y axis 
            plt.ylabel('f(x)') 
            # giving a title to my graph 
            expr += F"\n in range {x_start} to {x_end} step {x_step}"
            plt.title(expr)   
            # function to show the plot 
            plt.show() 
    else:
        print("{0} = {1}".format(expr,evalExpr(expr)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Can you provide us more information about the purpose of the code (what made you write it) and in what Python version you wrote it?

Comment: Thanks! I was using python 3.8. I want to learn python, and I was thinking that coding something is better that just follow some tutorials. That's why I try to write something I was made earlier in c++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mention that this was originally C++ code, well it shows.

First, style. Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It recommends writing `if condition` instead of `if(condition)` and using `lower_case` instead of `camelCase` for variables and functions.

You should also have a look at the standard library and [this excellent blog post about better looping](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html). You can also directly return the result of e.g. a boolean expression. Here are how I might write some of your functions:

```
def check_brackets(s):
    """
     Function checks brackets in string
     s: string with function
     returns: 0 -> brackets failure / 1 -> brackets ok 
    """

    open_brackets = 0
    for c in s:
        if c == "(":
            open_brackets += 1
        elif c == ")":
            if open_brackets:
                open_brackets -= 1
            else:
                return False
    return open_brackets == 0
```

Note that this will not be fooled by e.g. `")("`, in contrast to your code.

```
from itertools import groupby

def analyze_operations(s):
    """
     Function checks if there are two operators one after the other
     s: string with function
     returns: true if ok / false when err
    """
    s = s.replace(" ","")  # need to actually assign it, it is not in-place
    is_oper = map(lambda x: x in OPERS, s)
    return all(len(list(group)) == 1 for x, group in groupby(is_oper) if x)
```

Note that `str.replace` is not an in-place operation. So it does not do anything unless you assign the result to a variable. But since this seems to appear in many of your functions, you might want to do that in the calling code and not in every function.

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def analyze_op_after_CB(s):
    """
     Function checks if there is operator after closing bracket
     s: string with function
     returns: true if ok / false when err
    """
    for c1, c2 in pairwise(s.replace(" ","")):
        if (c1 == ")" 
            and c2 not in OPERS 
            and c2 != ")"):
            return False
    return True
```

The `pairwise` function is a recipe from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module.

```
def eval_expr(s, x_val=1):
    """
    Function evaluate RPN string 
    s: string with function infix 
    x_val: value for x variable
    r: value
    """
    s = s.replace(" ", "")
    if not check_brackets(s):
        raise SyntaxError("The expression have unclosed brackets!")
    elif not analyze_operations(s):      
        raise SyntaxError("The expression have incorrectly written operators!")
    elif not analyze_op_after_CB(s):
        raise SyntaxError("Missing operator after closing bracket!")

    stack = []
    for x in to_RPN(s, x_val):
        if isinstance(x, float):
            stack.append(x)
        elif x in OPERS:
            b, a = stack.pop(), stack.pop()
            stack.append(OPERS[x](a, b))
        elif x in FUNCTIONS:
            stack.append(FUNCTIONS[x](stack.pop()))
    if len(stack) != 1:
        raise SyntaxError("More than one value remains on stack")
    return round(stack[0], DEC_PLACES)        #return rounded result
```

The hardest part is of course to rewrite the conversion to the reverse polish notation, so I will leave that for now :)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Could you explain why use pairwise instead of for loop?

Comment: @Arek Because pairwise does what it says, iterating over pairs. No need for range checking, special casing the end, explicit indexing (which does not work with all iterables).

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do your version function analyze_operations(s) but it fails with: 12+2*(3*4+10/5)

Comment: @Arek: Fixed. It was failing because it determined that there were more than one non-operations in a row (which is fine of course, but I was not filtering for it). Thanks for the other edits!

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a interesting program.

## General

It took me a while (a few seconds) to figure out the meaning of
"i:" and "r:" in the docstrings, perhaps "parameters" and 
"returns" are more clear.

## function checkBrackets

I do not see the use of the `continue`'s in this case, the if-then
statement will finish anyway quickly.

I do not understand the variable name `wynik`, this will have to do with
languages i think seeing `raise("Błąd! Nieznana funkcja.")` later on.

I think the return value should be a bool and

```
if(wynik != 0): wynik = 0
else: wynik = 1
return wynik
```

should be

```
return wynik == 0
```

## function analizeOperations

This method could be better named `checkNoAdjacientOperators`

The replace method is not *inplace*, instead it returns a modified
string, so

```
sFun.replace(" ","")
```

should be

```
sFun = sFun.replace(" ","")
```

If the first character is an operator the functions checks the character with index -1, which results in a check for the last character, this is not what you want, so

```
for i in range(len(sFun)):
```

should be

```
for i in range(1, len(sFun)):
```

The variable `ok` can be skipped by changing

```
                ok = False
                break
```

with

```
                return False
```

and the final return statement with `return True` (although
*no multiple returns* evangilists might protest).

## function analizeOpAfterCB

Same remarks as for method `analizeOperations`.

## function toRPN

too much to handle for me now...

Comment: `checkNoAdjacientOperators`: I prefer the *adjacent* spelling :)